# Xamarin Forms - How to get selected item in picker?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a picker. I need to get the **ProvinceID** I tried to get the **ProvinceID** using the code below. but I cannot get the **ProvinceID**. I can only get the text inside the picker which is the province name. How can I get the **ProvinceID** and What is the difference between **ItemsSource** and **ItemDisplayBinding**?

> **codePicker.ItemsSource[codePicker.SelectedIndex].ToString()** - I tried to use this code to see if I can get the ProvinceID.
>   Sample Data:
>   **Province**: Nueva Ecija - This is what the picker displays
>   **ProvinceID**: NE210 - This is what I need to get

```
<local:CustomPicker x:Name="provincePicker" SelectedIndexChanged="provincePicker_SelectedIndexChanged" Unfocused="provincePicker_Unfocused" SelectedItem="{Binding DisplayText}" ItemsSource="{Binding ProvinceID}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding DisplayText}" StyleClass="fieldForm" IsEnabled="True">
    <local:CustomPicker.FontFamily>
         <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
             <On Platform="Android" Value="HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt.otf#HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt"/>
         </OnPlatform>
    </local:CustomPicker.FontFamily>
</local:CustomPicker>

var getCode = conn.QueryAsync<RetailerGroupTable>("SELECT * FROM tblRetailerGroup WHERE RetailerCode=?", code);
var resultCount = getCode.Result.Count;

if (resultCount > 0)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++)
   {
       var result = getCode.Result[i];
       provincePicker.SelectedItem = result.ProvinceID;
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this `codePicker.ItemsSource[codePicker.SelectedIndex].ProvinceID.ToString()`?

Comment: @CGPA6.4 there is an error I cannot add .ProvinceID

Comment: Try this `private void OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Picker picker = sender as Picker;
    var selectedItem = picker.SelectedItem; // This is the model selected in the picker
}` might help you. In xaml assign `OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged` this method to ItemSelected option.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 I used selectedItem.ToString() the result is Data.RetailerGroupTable

Comment: Do not use `selectedItem.ToString()` Instead use  `selectedItem.ProvinceID.ToString()`

Comment: There is an error 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ProvinceID' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found @CGPA6.4

Comment: Are you able to do like this `selectedItem[0].ProvinceID.ToString();`.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 no, still there is an error

Comment: If possible you share zip file of your project.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 please see updated code

Comment: Why don't you have this event `<Picker SelectedIndexChanged="Picker_SelectedIndexChanged"></Picker>` in your xaml?

Comment: I have that I found a work around how can I set a selected item in my picker? @CGPA6.4

Comment: For that ask different question with different heading.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 can you help me please I am so desperate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is quite simple actually:

- Get Selected Item of the Picker something like this;

  ```
  var selectedItem = provincePicker.SelectedItem as RetailerGroupTable;
  var provinceId= selectedItem.ProvinceId;
  ```
- I would also suggest you subscribe to the SelectedIndexChanged event in your picker so you know that there was a change in the picker selection this can be done in two ways :

  **XAML**

  ```
  <Picker SelectedIndexChanged="Picker_SelectedIndexChanged">
  ```

  **C#**

  ```
  provincePicker.SelectedIndexChanged+=Picker_SelectedIndexChanged;
  ```

> What is the difference between ItemsSource and ItemDisplayBinding?

**As per the Xamarin docs**

> `ItemsSource` of type `IList`, is the source list of items to display, which defaults to null. whereas When binding to a list of objects, the `Picker` must be told which property to display from each object. This is achieved by setting the `ItemDisplayBinding` property to the required property from each object.

**Comments:**

`ItemsSource` is an `IList` and hence has an `Enumerator`, how that works is it keeps track of how many items do you have in your list of items and thus creates that many spots to fill, `ItemDisplayBinding`, on the other hand, has nothing to do with any of these things all it does is it tells your `Picker` that I want this item to be displayed into the picker options when my `Picker` is in turn ready.

I hope I am making sense, Revert in case of queries.

**UPDATE**

**XAML**

```
<local:CustomPicker x:Name="provincePicker" SelectedIndexChanged="provincePicker_SelectedIndexChanged" Unfocused="provincePicker_Unfocused" ItemsSource="{Binding ProvinceID}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding DisplayText}" StyleClass="fieldForm" IsEnabled="True">
<local:CustomPicker.FontFamily>
     <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
         <On Platform="Android" Value="HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt.otf#HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt"/>
     </OnPlatform>
</local:CustomPicker.FontFamily>
```

**C#**

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>{
 var result = conn.QueryAsync<RetailerGroupTable>("SELECT * FROM tblRetailerGroup WHERE RetailerCode=?", code).Result.FirstOrDefault();
provincePicker.SelectedItem = result;
                    });
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184329/discussion-between-g-hakim-and-lawrence-agulto).